# Conditional statement produces unwanted action in Android App

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following code for the user to pick a winner between four options.  The variables p1, p2, p3 and p4 are determined by a compare method prior to being used here (the value is always between -3 and 3, 3 being a winner). The problem I'm having is that sometimes, and only sometimes a WINNING evaluation returns the toast for a TIE. I've include the variables in the toast message, only to make sure the correct value is being passed. All values are correct. So I'm at a loss. Can anyone give me any ideas why this might be happening?  It seemed to be only happening when one player evaluated to 3, and another to -3.  So I 'artificially' inflated all variables by 3, so that same scenario would then return a 6 and a 3.  But the problem persists.  The only thing I can think of is it may be a buffering, or cache issue. But all the variables are re-initialized to 0 on each pass by an onClick action.  Please help. Thank you.

```
    public void EvaluatePlayer1(View view) {
    if(p1>=p2 && p1>=p3 && p1>=p4){
        if(p1 == p2 || p1 == p3 || p1 == p4){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " It's a tie.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " You chose the winner!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + "You chose a loser!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if(p1 == p2 || p1 == p3 || p1 == p4){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " It's a tie.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " You chose the winner!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

to

```
if(p1 > p2 && p1 > p3 && p1 > p4){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " You chose the winner!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p1 + " It's a tie.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }
```

Comment: Let me know if it does.

Comment: So much for that... it turns out, this way, ties are evaluated as wins. Thank you anyway.  I've found a work around using slightly different code.  I just said if p1 = 3, it wins, and kept the original conditions to evaluate ties, which they do just fine.

Comment: I completely changed my answer.  That should work because if p1 is already equal to or greater than all the others and it is now checked with greater than everything else then it can not be a tie and the only other option is that it was guessed correctly.

Comment: Yes. This works. And I do prefer not to hard code the value, since if I add players, it won't be the same. Thanks.  This makes sense, and it won't throw that weird result. LOL, I have no reputation, so I can't even upvote you...

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing the case where you have a tie with a value that isn't the actual winner (see my comments)

```
if(p1>=p2 && p1>=p3 && p1>=p4) {  // can have 2 values >= p1
    if(p1 == p2 || p1 == p3 || p1 == p4) // FIXME: what if we tie with second place?
```

i think you might need to simplify that comparison a little and break it out a little more logically. something like this

```
if(p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>p4)
    // p1 beat all other scores = winner
else if(p2>p1 || p3>p1 || p4>p1)
    // at least one other score beats p1 = loser
else
    if (p1 == max(p2, p3, p4))  // where max returns the highest other value
        // we equal the max of the other scores = tie for 1st place
    else
        // how did we get here?
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I went a little different way, cause I still don't really see where the conflict is.  Ties can occur with values of 2, 1 or 0, that's why the first condition is >=, and the second part is || because all players can tie with a value of 0 across the board. But when p1 > than all others, it has a value of 3, and cannot be tied. In other words, p1 can only have a value of 3 if it beats all others.  I do see how it would be better to just use > all for an outright winner though. thanks again.

Comment: @Oscar Glad you found a fix. Just FYI, so that you can see the conflict here's a use case where it occurs

    'p1 = 2'
    'p2 = 2'
    'p3 = 3'
    'p4 = -1'

p2 and p3 satisfy your condition, then you test for a tie before testing for a win or loss and the tie with p2 is found, thus returning a tie rather than a win

Comment: meh, comment formatting isn't good on here, hopefully you get the idea